# WinRT: Open previously opened files again after close

Tags: c#, file, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I have a simple writing app for Windows 8.1, which I'm currently expanding to include tabs. I am also adding an autosave feature to these tabs, so that when the user 'closes' the app, it writes the content of the file and the path, if its an existing file, to a txt file in the localstorage.

This works great when the files are unsaved. The user closes the app, and after reopening all his tabs are there again, with the latest changes.

The problem I have is when the file is already saved. I store the path in the txt, so I thought I'd just open the file again on opening of the app, but the problem is that I am not allowed to open just any file on the system. The user could have opened a file from his C: drive, which I cannot read (for instance as described [here](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/06/windows-8-how-to-read-files-in-winrt.html)).

Any ideas on how I could solve this. I'm afraid that what I'm trying to do will not be possible.

If needed I could show some code about saving the autosave file, but I didn't think I could show anything relevant to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Vasile said once the application closes you lose access to the StorageFile's that were outside the sandbox.

However WinRT does provide the [StorageApplicationPermissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions.aspx) class where you can store those permissions to the file. You can then store the token for subsequent launches of the app.

Comment: Thanks Nigel, this is exactly what I needed!
I'm now adding the opened files to the future access list in the StorageApplicationPermissions class and get a token back for each of them. I store that token in my autosave file. When it reopens, I request the files again using the tokens.

As an added bonus, it tracks if the files where moved! I just give it the token and it gives me the file if its still in an accessible location.

Answer (score 1):

It's cause the app is sandboxed and cannot access other storage areas than the `Local Storage` unless you involve user interaction via an Open picker.

Let's say you save the file on `C:\`. Also, save it on the `Local Storage` of the app. Next time, when the app is loaded, in the tabs will be shown the text file from the `Local Storage` - do your edits, save it somewhere in the PC and overwrite the file from the `LocalStorage`. In this way, the file you work with is actually the one in the local storage.

You have to be careful here with the namings. If you save `SampleFile.txt` on `C:\` and then you create another one also called `SampleFile.txt` but on `D:\`, when you copy the file in the `LocalStorage`, it should be different from the first one. Here, you'll have to come up with yourown rules.

Comment: Thank you for the help Vasile.
I'm assigning each opened file a unique id, and store the token (from Nigels answer), so no paths are stored. I'm avoiding the duplicate file names this way.